How do I tune Redis Cache
We are receiving a lot of Redis exceptions, and our application is slowing. The database CPU is maxing out at 100% and bringing our application down. This is a common Exception:
Timeout performing HMGET (10000ms), inst: 0, qu: 3155, qs: 0, aw: True, bw: Starting, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint: xxxxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: shopXXXX, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=100,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=348,Free=32419,Min=100,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
This makes it look like Redis is not being used at all, 0 busy IOCP threads, 10 or 10 available dedicated pol threads. I think our application is busy doing other things as there are 348 busy worker threads. So I do not understand why we have a time out exception for Redis?
We have tried increasing the Min Worker Threads to 300. This solved our Redis Exceptions, We are not seeing any of the time out exceptions. I am not sure why this helped?. But now our database appears to be overwhelmed, although CPU and Memory are normal, we are seeing a lot of timeout Exceptions like this:
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. , [SupplierItemCode] The wait operation timed out.
Has the increase in minimum worker threads caused this? Should we try lowering the worker minimum? Should we try increasing the IOCP minimum? Should we increase our database connections which are set to 100?
